# Spring WS + Wss4jSecurityInterceptor + MTOM memory issues

Tags: java, out-of-memory, spring-ws, mtom, axis

This seems to be somewhat a longstanding question, and no definitive solution so far: situations where your incoming MTOM messages get inlined to the SOAP message, crashing the application due to memory usage.

I'm creating a file upload webservice with Spring WS (2.1) using Apache Axiom (1.2.13) because the files I receive are big:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="payloadCaching" value="true"/>
    <property name="attachmentCaching" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

I'm using JAXB (2.2.5) for XML data marshalling, but it inlines attachments, so for endpoints that handle attachments I use `SoapMessage` directly; not what I would prefer, but acceptable. Up to this point is fine with this setup, and I can upload very big files. The problem is that I also need authentication, for which I'm using Apache WSS4J 1.6.6:

```
<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken"/>
    <property name="securementActions" value="NoSecurity"/>
</bean>
```

When the interceptor does the message validation, it also inlines the attachment data to the body of the message, eating lots of memory and generating `OutOfMemoryError` on reasonably sized messages:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(Arrays.java:3209) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:215) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xni.XMLString.toString(XMLString.java:185) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractDOMParser.characters(AbstractDOMParser.java:1188) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:463) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:807) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.parse(RegistryDocumentBuilder.java:163) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.2.0]
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124) ~[na:1.6.0_14]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.support.AxiomUtils.toDocument(AxiomUtils.java:133) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.axiom.AxiomSoapMessage.getDocument(AxiomSoapMessage.java:201) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.validateMessage(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:561) ~[spring-ws-security-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.handleRequest(AbstractWsSecurityInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-ws-security-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.handleRequest(DelegatingSmartEndpointInterceptor.java:78) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:224) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:173) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:88) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:59) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:221) ~[spring-ws-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789) ~[org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar:3.1.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) ~[javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar:2.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) ~[javax.servlet_1.0.0.0_2-5.jar:2.5]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.2.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.2.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.2.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.2.0]
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3591) ~[weblogic.jar:10.3.2.0]
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) ~[com.bea.core.weblogic.security.identity_1.1.2.0.jar:1.1.2.0]
```

I haven't found a way to fix this undesired inlining so far. I don't want to read and handle the header manually, it would make WSS4J pointless, and my code less flexible to handle future requirements.

[This thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?78233-SpringWS-Security-MTOM-and-java-lang-OutOfMemoryError) suggests fooling the interceptor into using a copy of the message containing only the header, but I couldn't implement it (it is a few years old, the API may be changed). This would probably forbid the use of encrypted and signed messages (as a reply points out), but so far not a requirement for me. [This other thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?100951-Problems-with-Spring-WS-Streaming-Attachments-with-Security-Interceptor) suggests sticking with Axiom 1.2.8, which did nothing, and also setting the `validateRequest` flag on the Axiom factory to `false` (this one sounds strange, as it disables security - no error but no security, what would be the point of it?).

So, anybody can help me with a solution to this issue? Fixing JAXB, tricking the WSS4J interceptor, or some other solution? Any help is welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: JAXB allows an `AttachmentMarshaller` to be set on a `Marshaller` and an `AttachmentUnmarshaller` to be set on an `Unmarshaller`.  These are provided by the JAX-WS implementation.  The JAXB implementation will give these attachment handlers a chance to handle the binary data, if they don't they will inline the binary data (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/jaxb-web-services-and-binary-data.html).  My suspicion is that your issue is related to Spring WS.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I didn't include it in this question, but I was having problems to create webservices for file download too, that were also inlining the files. With your advice I hope I can fix it too. Looks like there are no methods to plug them, so I'll try to extend Spring's `Jaxb2Marshaller` and set the (un)marshaller in `initJaxbMarshaller` and `initJaxbUnmarshaller`. I'll post a reply as soon as I have something =)

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan I couldn't try the attachment marshallers, couldn't wire them properly. I created a new question here specifically about this JAXB issue. I'd appreciate your help, if you could. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564899/spring-ws-with-axiom-jaxb-is-inlining-mtom-attachments

Comment: @mdrg - Can you please share atleast the pseudo configuration of your full working file. I am unable to get Axiom and wss4j working together. Facing error given at http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?139770-PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping-with-Wss4jSecurityInterceptor-raises-SOAPProcessingEx  and also at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632687/payloadrootqnameendpointmapping-with-wss4jsecurityinterceptor-causing-soapproces . Please help. Thanks