# PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping with Wss4jSecurityInterceptor causing SOAPProcessingException

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-ws, wss4j

I am using below configuration, for PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping with Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

```
<bean id="endpointMapping" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="{http://com/clickandbuy/mywebservice/}employeeById_Request">serviceEndPoint</prop>
            <prop key="{http://com/clickandbuy/mywebservice/}employeeByFile_Request">serviceEndPoint</prop>
            <prop key="{http://com/clickandbuy/mywebservice/}employeeBySecurity_Request">serviceEndPoint</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor"/>
            <ref local="wsSecurityInterceptor"/> 
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="wsSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
    <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="springSecurityHandler" />
</bean>

<bean id="springSecurityHandler"
  class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</bean>
```

When no interceptor is provided,

```
 <!--<ref local="wsSecurityInterceptor"/> -->
```

It works fine. But if above line is active, that is interceptor is provided, it gives error

```
.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder:316||||>> Starting to process SOAP          1.1 message 
<<||2013-07-13 22:36:57,922||http-apr-8080-exec-      35|DEBUG|org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder:273||||>> Build the    OMElement Envelope by the StaxSOAPModelBuilder 
<<||2013-07-13 22:36:57,923||http-apr-8080-exec-35|DEBUG|org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder:273||||>> Build the OMElement Header by the StaxSOAPModelBuilder 
<<||2013-07-13 22:36:57,923||http-apr-8080-exec-35|DEBUG|org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.builder.StAXSOAPModelBuilder:273||||>> Build the OMElement Security by the StaxSOAPModelBuilder 
<<||2013-07-13 22:36:57,924||http-apr-8080-exec-35|DEBUG|org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher:273||||>> Testing endpoint adapter [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.MessageEndpointAdapter@6e369c05] 
<<||2013-07-13 22:36:57,925||http-apr-8080-exec-35|DEBUG|org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPHeaderImpl:426||||>>     org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: An attempt was made to add a normal OMEl    ement as a child of a SOAPHeader.  This is not supported.  The child should be a   SOAPHeaderBlock.
at org.apache.axiom.soap.impl.llom.SOAPHeaderImpl.addChild(SOAPHeaderImpl.java:423)
```

Please share if something is wrong, or any proper way to configure spring-ws PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping with Wss4jSecurityInterceptor

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think there was some error with spring-ws 1.5.6 version, I switched to version 2.0.0 and it works fine